# How to use map for class method within another class method in Python

Tags: python

I want to define a class method which applies a different class method to a list - I thought the below would work but it doesn't seem to, am I missing something obvious?

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
          pass

    def method1(self, data):
        do some stuff

    def method2(self, iterable):
        map(self.method1, iterable)
        do some more stuff
```

As a concrete example, method2 is applying method1 to each element of a list but the actual content of method1 (printing) doesn't seem to be executing:

```
class Foo():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.factor = 2
        
    def method1(self, num):
        print(num*self.factor)
        
    
    def method2(self, ls):
        map(self.method1, ls)

f = Foo()
f.method2([1,2,3])
```

I would expect this to print 2, 4, 6 but nothing is printed.

Comment: I think you are making confusion with class methods and (instance) methods... I think you mean the latter one

Comment: Could you expand on _"doesn't seem to [work]"_? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for ambiguity, have added dumb toy example - I would expect f.method2([1,2,3]) to print [2,4,6] but although the code runs nothing is printed

Comment: Then the answer below is correct - `map` is _lazy_.

Comment: ahhhh, yeah that make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns a generator (in Python 3), so you still need to iterate over it:

```
def method2(self, iterable):
    for val in map(self.method1, iterable):
        do some stuff with val
```

If you don't care about the return values, you could always just wrap it in a list: `list(map(self.method1, iterable))`.

Comment: A list comprehension would be e.g. `[self.method1(value) for value in iterable]`, but using a list/list comprehension for side effects isn't idiomatic - you're building a list you don't need.